# Is it possible? Three OpenBSD 6.0-current firewall bridges with only one OpenBSD Server?

Tags: openbsd, bridge, pf

**Is it possible to configure several firewall bridges with one OpenBSD server which has 6 nic's. In this case 3 OpenBSD firewall bridges from each other completely independent?**

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf

net.inet.ip.ttl=255
net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
net.inet.ip.redirect=0

cat /etc/hostname.bnx0
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bnx1
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bnx2
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bnx3
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bnx4
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bnx5
up
-inet6

cat /etc/hostname.bridge0
add bnx0
add bnx1
blocknonip bnx0
blocknonip bnx1
link0
edge bnx0
edge bnx1
spanpriority 0
proto rstp
ptp bnx0
ptp bnx1
up

cat /etc/hostname.bridge1
add bnx2
add bnx3
blocknonip bnx2
blocknonip bnx3
link0
edge bnx2
edge bnx3
spanpriority 0
proto rstp
ptp bnx2
ptp bnx3
up

cat /etc/hostname.bridge2
add bnx4
add bnx5
blocknonip bnx4
blocknonip bnx5
link0
edge bnx4
edge bnx5
spanpriority 0
proto rstp
ptp bnx4
ptp bnx5
up

cat /etc/pf.conf

set block-policy return
set state-policy if-bound
set optimization aggressive

ext_if_1 = "{bnx0}"
int_if_1 = "{bnx1}"

ext_if_2 = "{bnx2}"
int_if_2 = "{bnx3}"

ext_if_3 = "{bnx4}"
int_if_3 = "{bnx5}"

lan_ip_1 = "{12.13.14.254/28}"

lan_ip_2 = "{13.14.15.254/29}"

lan_ip_3 = "{14.15.16.254/24}"

icmp_type = "{ 0, 3, 4, 8 }"

match log (user) on bnx set (tos ef) scrub (max-mss 1460, min-ttl 255, random-id, reassemble tcp, no-df)

block log all
block log quick inet6 all
block return log
block return-rst log inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 1) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 2) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 3) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 4) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 5) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 6) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 8) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 9) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 10) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 11) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 12) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 13) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 14) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 15) inet proto tcp all
block return-rst(ttl 16) inet proto tcp all

block log quick inet6 all

block log quick from any to {192.168/16, 10/8, 172.16/12, 169.254/16, 224/4, 240/4, 0/8, 198.18/15, 192.0.2.0/24, 127/8, 255.255.255.255/32}

block log quick from {192.168/16, 10/8, 172.16/12, 169.254/16, 127/8, 224/4, 240/4, 0/8, 198.18/15, 192.0.2.0/24, 255.255.255.255/32} to any

pass log quick inet proto icmp from any to any icmp-type $icmp_type keep state (max 1000, max-src-nodes 50, source-track rule)

pass in log quick on {$int_if_1, $int_if_2, $int_if_3} inet proto udp from {$lan_ip_1, $lan_ip_2, $lan_ip_3} port >1024 to any port {53, 123} user = unknown keep state (max 10000, max-src-nodes 5000, source-track rule)

pass out log quick on {$ext_if_1, $ext_if_2, $ext_if_3} inet proto udp from {$lan_ip_1, $lan_ip_2, $lan_ip_3} port >1024 to any port {53, 123} user = unknown keep state (max 10000, max-src-nodes 5000, source-track rule)

pass in log quick on $int_if_1 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_1 port >1024 os "unknown" to any port {22, 25, 53, 80, 443, 587, 1194} user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 10000, max-src-conn 5000, max-src-nodes 1, source-track > rule) tag mylan_ip_1

pass out log quick on $ext_if_1 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_1 port > >1024 os "unknown" to any port {22, 25, 53, 80, 443, 587, 1194} user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 10000, max-src-conn 5000, max-src-nodes 1, source-track rule) tagged mylan_ip_1

pass in log quick on $int_if_2 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_2 > port >1024 os "unknown" to any port 22 user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 10, max-src-conn 1, max-src-nodes 1, source-track rule) tag mylan_ip_2

pass out log quick on $ext_if_2 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_2 port >1024 os "unknown" to any port 22 user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 10, max-src-conn 1, max-src-nodes 1, source-track rule) tagged mylan_ip_2

pass in log quick on $int_if_3 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_3 port >1024 os "unknown" to any port 443 user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 100, max-src-conn 8, max-src-nodes 1, source-track rule) tag mylan_ip_3

pass out log quick on $ext_if_3 inet proto tcp from $lan_ip_3 port >1024 os "unknown" to any port 443 user = unknown flags S/SAFRUP modulate state (max 100, max-src-conn 8, max-src-nodes 1, source-track rule) tagged mylan_ip_3
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible, people have done a lot worse.  Do you have any specific question?

Comment: Thank you very much,  because my HP Server has only two NIC's I could not test it. I have firewall bridges for sixteen years in use, but only with two nic's per HP Server. Since I now have an HP Server as a Dual Homed Host without routing, but with two uplink ports, but a second HP Server with 6 NIC's want to configure as a firewall bridge. Therefore the question as I have no experience with such a constellation as a firewall bridge with 6 Nic's and three firewall bridges on a Server. Thank you very much.

Comment: The third firewall bridge is to the safeguard of the two iLo4 approaches by the server and the bridge itself.

Comment: It's possible.  It isn't necessarily a _good_ idea.  Bridging firewalls were never very efficient on OpnBSD, you get swamped by interrupts far sooner that you'd normally run into other limitations.  IIRC there was a post by Theo from a few years ago where he basically discouraged people from using such things for any significant traffic.

Comment: To you have a link of this post from Theo

Comment: Sorry, this is all from memory (and I'm an old fart at that).  Ask on the OpenBSD lists for up to date information.